# Help with すぐ in a sentence

Tags: translation

> 外套に**すぐ**シャツを着た男

Is すぐ there with its usual connotations of “close by, right there”? I can’t make sense of this sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 外套に**すぐ**シャツを着た男

I think the すぐ means "directly".

I understand the phrase as: "a man wearing only an undershirt under a coat" (wearing nothing between the undershirt and the coat).

But I think it'd be more natural/common to say it as 「外套**のすぐ下に**シャツを着た男」

Comment: 出典は宮沢賢治なのね・・・・・